# Django error: "Accessor for field clashes with related field"

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I run "python manage.py runserver", the following 2 error messages are printed 4 times:

```
transcription.treatment: Accessor for field 'treatment_ptr' clashes with related field 'Treatment.treatment'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'treatment_ptr'.
transcription.treatment: Reverse query name for field 'treatment_ptr' clashes with related field 'Treatment.treatment'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'treatment_ptr'.
```

Below is my code. In shared/models.py:

```
class Treatment(models.Model):
    code = RandomCharField(length=6)
    experiment_id = models.CharField(max_length = 10, null = True)


    base_pay = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=20)

    def was_started_recently(self):
        expiry_time = timedelta(minutes = 5)
        if datetime.now() - self.time_started < expiry_time:
            return True

class OfferTreatment(Treatment):
    max_offer_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=50)
    increment_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)

    def offer_choices(self):
       return range(0, self.max_offer_amount + 1, self.increment_amount)

    def is_valid_offer(amount):
        return amount in self.offer_choices()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

In games/transcription/models.py:

```
class Treatment(shared.models.OfferTreatment):
    short_name = 'tr'
    long_name = 'Transcription'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this the entire model?

Answer (score 1):

You have two models called Treatment. And although OfferTreatment is abstract, the shared version of Treatment is not. You should probably mark that as abstract, and also rename it to something like BaseTreatment.

Alternatively, you may want to make transcription.Treatment into a proxy model.